# How to implement the deprecated methods of Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a small problem but dont understand how to get out of this.

I created a class for providing Notifications, but these lines are marked deprecated:

```
...
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time); // deprecated in API level 11
...
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent); // deprecated in API level 11
...
```

Alternative methods are:

```
...
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build(); // available from API level 11 and onwards
...
```

Can i write a code something like:

```
if(API_level < 11)
{
...
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time); // deprecated in API level 11
    ...
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent); // deprecated in API level 11
    ...
}

else
{
    ...
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
             .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
             .setContentText(subject)
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
             .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
             .build(); // available from API level 11 and onwards
    ...
}
```

I providing the minimum sdk version as "8".

**Edit:**

I did like below:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TaskDetails.class), 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } 
        else
        {
            // what to write here
        }
```

What can i write for `else` portion ??

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure to set targetSdkVersion as 11 or more.

Comment: @Tarun Yes my target sdk version is set to "17" and if the "if...else" condition can handle this, can you please provide me a sample code or a reference so that i can get a little hint.

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. If else will handle as per the api level.

Comment: @Tarun That was just an idea i wonder if i could write this. but how to get the current API version, that device might be using...

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);`

Comment: @Tarun voted for useful. I got it. Please check the question, i am making an edit in it within a minute.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is how i ended up to the solution:

```
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent); // This method is removed from the Android 6.0
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(text).setWhen(time)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text).build();

            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
```

**Edit:**

The above solution works. Still, since, `NotificationCompat.Builder` class was introduced, we can skip the if condition for checking that compares current API version. So, we can simply remove the `if...else` condition, and go with:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                      .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(text).setWhen(time)
                      .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                      .setContentText(text).build();
mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

Comment: I used `NotificationCompact.Builder`.

Comment: FYI `setLatestEventInfo()` was removed from the SDK in Android 6.0. [source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html#android.app.Notification.setLatestEventInfo_removed%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: time should be System.currentTimeMillis() if you want the current time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27721837/211457

Comment: where i can found NotificationCompat.Builder? how i can include it in my project? EDIT: its on android.support.v4

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way to get the level.

```
 final int sdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);

if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
...
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time); // deprecated in API level 11
...
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent); // deprecated in API level 11
...
}
else
{
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build(); // available from API level 11 and onwards
}
```

All the version codes can be found at this [developer link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: Heyy, i got errors in these lines you wrote in else portion, telling that `call requires API level 11 or more`

Comment: Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB = 11 so else part will be called only if the api is greater than 11.

Comment: Ya thats fine. But how to remove those errors ?? With this, i can't even run my project. Please give me some solution to this...

Comment: What is the error? Can you paste it here... Add your manifest uses-sdk  also.