# I want to put alert on service

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to create an event reminder alert from [eventreminder](https://github.com/dyaskur/event-reminder). But why is the alert not showing?

I have android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in manifest.

This is code of eventreminder service:

```
package com.example.android.eventreminder;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/* This class is responsible for notification when an alarm and proximity alert are fired
 * Sets up pending intent which is used by notification system. 
 * Pending intent contains intent to start ViewReminder Activity when notification is clicked*/
public class EventReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {
    private eventDB mDbHelper;
    private String notificationTitle;

    public EventReminderService() {
        super("EventReminderService");
    }

    @Override
    void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
        /* Status bar notification */
        /* when the notification is selected from status bar,
         * ViewReminder activity will be started using rowId as part of 
         * pending intent. ViewReminder activity will be used to display
         * event data, to delete event and to snooze time-based event*/
        AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("tanchulai")
                .setMessage("bucuo de tanchulai")

                .create();

        d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        d.show();


        Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(eventDB.KEY_ROWID);

        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Add reminder activity will started when notification is selected */
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ViewReminder.class); 
        notificationIntent.putExtra(eventDB.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

        int rowID = rowId.intValue();
        /* set pending intent */
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, rowID, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Log.d("TAG", "PI in ERSer for: "+rowID);
        /* set notification for status bar */
        Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning,
                                        getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message),
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());


        mDbHelper = new eventDB(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        Cursor notificationData = mDbHelper.fetchEvent(rowId); 
        /* get title of the event*/
        notificationTitle = notificationData.getString(
                notificationData.getColumnIndexOrThrow(eventDB.KEY_TITLE)); 

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, notificationTitle,
                                getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi); 

        notificationData.close();
        mDbHelper.close();

        /* Set default notification sound */
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
        /* Cancel notification after selection by user */
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

        int id = (int)((long)rowId); 
        /* produce notification on status bar */
        mgr.notify(id, note);

    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielNugent i dont use notification builder. so what i must to do?

Comment: It looks like you're using deprecated methods, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852270/how-to-implement-the-deprecated-methods-of-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services run separately from Activity(in order to run at background). So service don't have window and you can't show dialog or toast. You should send data to activity, and handle it there.

You can use `BroadcastReceiver` for sending data to `Activity` from `Service`.