# Cannot Resolve Method setLatestEventInfo

Tags: android

I am working on Notifications and I have to use `setLatestEventInfo`. However, Android Studio shows the following error message:

> cannot resolve method setLatestEventinfo

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void createNotification(Context context, String registrationID) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Registration Successfull",System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,RegistrationResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("registration_ID",registrationID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,"Registration","Successfully Registered",pendingIntent);
}
```

Or if their is another way to do so, kindly suggest me that.

Comment: `setLatestEventInfo` is `deprecated `  do it using `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Well below is a simple example of working with Notifications, go through it, hope it helps!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnShow, btnClear;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialise();

        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //API level 11
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.rj.notitfications.SECACTIVITY");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builder.setAutoCancel(false);
                builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
                builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");               
                builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setOngoing(true);
                builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
                builder.setNumber(100);
                builder.build();

                myNotication = builder.getNotification();
                manager.notify(11, myNotication);

                /*
                //API level 8
                Notification myNotification8 = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "this is ticker text 8", System.currentTimeMillis());

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 2, intent2, 0);
                myNotification8.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "API level 8", "this is api 8 msg", pendingIntent2);
                manager.notify(11, myNotification8);
                */

            }
        });

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                manager.cancel(11);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialise() {
        btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowNotification);
        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearNotification);        
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowNotification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Notification" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClearNotification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Notification" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity that will be opened on click of Notification,

```
public class SecActivity extends Activity {

}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570767/setlatesteventinfo-method-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0); in this method fourth param is for passing flags. What it means if you pass 0?

Comment: @r j, Thank You! It's really helpful for basic notification purpose.

Comment: @r j, How to make it clear able on click of notification?

Comment: what is the 11 stand for ?

Comment: 11 is the ID of that notification, if you wanna perform further operations on this notification you can use this ID. For more info, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String, int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: buiilder.build() requires API 16 or more. What to do for earlier versions?

Comment: 'getNotification()' is deprecated as of API 16...  What do we do with later versions?

Answer (score 43):

According to : https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html

This method was removed in M (api 23). So if your compile SDK version is set to api 23+ you'll see this issue.

Answer (score 35):

You write you **have** to use `setLatestEventInfo`. Does it mean you are ready to have your app not compatible with more recent Android versions? I strongly suggest you to use the [support library v4](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) that contains the `NotificationCompat` class for app using API 4 and over.

If you really do not want to use the support library (even with Proguard optimization, using NotificationCompat will add a good 100Ko on the final app), an other way is to use reflection. If you deploy your app on an Android version that still has the deprecated `setLatestEventInfo`, first of all you should check if you are in such an environment, and then you use reflection to access the method.

This way, Android Studio or the compiler will not complain, since the method is accessed at runtime, and not at compile time. For instance :

```
Notification notification = null;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    notification = new Notification();
    notification.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    try {
        Method deprecatedMethod = notification.getClass().getMethod("setLatestEventInfo", Context.class, CharSequence.class, CharSequence.class, PendingIntent.class);
        deprecatedMethod.invoke(notification, context, contentTitle, null, pendingIntent);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Method not found", e);
    }
} else {
    // Use new API
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    notification = builder.build();
}
```

Comment: You took that "have to" literally, kudos for the thoroughness. IMO the OP just read the documentation which states to use that method. For example [Running a service in the foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) still has a reference to that method.

Comment: Finally something that works so I can update my app with expansion files to API 23+ Thank you very much!!

Comment: For those that are encountering this problem in the context of the google play expansion library, in the package com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader, there is an updated version on github that is newer than the one that gets installed via the android studio sdk manager. https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion. This version does not use the deprecated setLatestEventInfo method.

Answer (score -4):

Go to project -> properties and set android-target 21

Comment: Perhaps this is correct (I don't know), but you don't give any hint to as why this would be a solution.

Comment: The reason it works is because the API is available on Android less than 23 and is deprecated starting with API Level 23.