# Android - How to show notification in API<11 using API

Tags: android, notifications

Before API 23(Android 6.0 Marshmallow), we could show notification using this code

```
Notification myNotification8 = new Notification(R.drawable.android, "this is ticker text 8", System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 2, intent2, 0);
            myNotification8.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "API level 8", "this is api 8 msg", pendingIntent2);
                NotificationManager manager = manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(11, myNotification8);
```

Getting this error:

> Cannot resolve method setLatestEventInfo

According to these [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32830640/2255924) and [documentation](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html), the method setLatestEventInfo was removed.

So question - is it possible to show notification in API<11 without changing **compileSdkVersion 23**?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities. The best way would be to use the [support library v4](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) that contains the `NotificationCompat` class for app using API 4 and over. But I guess it does not answer your question.

The other way is to use reflection. If you deploy your app on an Android version that still has the deprecated `setLatestEventInfo`, first you check you are in such an environment, and then you use reflection to access the method.

This way, Android Studio or the compiler will not complain, since the method is access in runtime, and not in compile time. For instance :

```
Notification notification = null;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    notification = new Notification();
    notification.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    try {
        Method deprecatedMethod = notification.getClass().getMethod("setLatestEventInfo", Context.class, CharSequence.class, CharSequence.class, PendingIntent.class);
        deprecatedMethod.invoke(notification, context, contentTitle, null, pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Method not found", e);
    }
else {
    // Use new API
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    notification = builder.build();
}
```