# cannot resolve setLatestEventInfo (Notfication)

Tags: android

I realize that this question has been asked before, but I just can't seem to integrate a working solution into my own code as I am still quite new to this side of Android Development.

I used this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo) as a reference, but I can't understand how to change it on my side.

Here is the code segment I would like to change:

```html
private void handleCommand(Intent intent) {
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.service_running);

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                text, System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Launcher.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text, text, contentIntent);

        startForegroundCompat(R.string.service_running, notification);

        startMonitorThread((ActivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can't understand your question please explain in proper way. What you want to do?

Comment: I would just like to know how to implement the `NotificationCompat.Builder` / `Notification.Builder` (which ever one is right) rather than the `setLatestEventInfo` which I know has been discontinued... I'm just not sure at all how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below link might be help you.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/03/example-of-using-notificationbuilder.html

Comment: just tried this, bit I get an error with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Any idea how I would be able to fix that?

Comment: Must be one or more of: `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`, `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, `Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION`, `Intent.FILL_IN_DATA`, `Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES`, `Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT`, `Intent.FILL_IN_PACKAGE`, `Intent.FILL_IN_SOURCE_BOUNDS`, `Intent.FILL_IN_SELECTOR`, `Intent.FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA`

Comment: set PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.