# Unknown method setLatestEventInfo

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make an auto update app and got the source code from here: https://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/downloads/detail?name=auto-update-apk-client_2012-10-04.tgz&can=2&q=

But i got an error "unknown method setLatestEventInfo"

Thanks for helping.

```
protected void raise_notification() {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

    String update_file = preferences.getString(UPDATE_FILE, "");
    if( update_file.length() > 0 ) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(AUTOUPDATE_HAVE_UPDATE);

        // raise notification
        Notification notification = new Notification(
                appIcon, appName + " update", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= NOTIFICATION_FLAGS;

        CharSequence contentTitle = appName + " update available";
        CharSequence contentText = "Select to install";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        notificationIntent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + update_file),
                ANDROID_PACKAGE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        nm.notify( NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    } else {
        nm.cancel( NOTIFICATION_ID );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method was deprecated in API level 11. You should be using `NotificationBuilder` instead.
Have a look at the [Building a Notification lesson](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346246/4230150) answer.