# setLatestEventInfo method cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am trying to implement a reminder feature for my application which is API 23.

However, the reminder feature contains an error whereby the method "setLatestEventInfo" cannot be resolved.

[image]

I have done some researching and it turns out that this method is deprecated in API 23. I know that there are similar questions out there, but the solutions did not work for me.

Below are the relevant codes:

```
 public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

    public ReminderService() {
        super("ReminderService");
            }

    @Override
    void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
        Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
        notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

        Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

        // An issue could occur if user ever enters over 2,147,483,647 tasks. (Max int value). 
        // I highly doubt this will ever happen. But is good to note. 
        int id = (int)((long)rowId);
        mgr.notify(id, note); 


    }
}
```

How can I solve this without downgrading my API level?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo

Answer (score 0):

Use [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) to build your notifications as in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

You can check the methods `setTicker`, `setSmallIcon`, `setContentTitle`, `setContentText`, `setContentIntent`, `setAutoCancel`, `setDefaults` to reproduce your behaviour.