# I am trying to generate notification on app,but i got error cannot resolve setLatestEventInfo() method

Tags: java, android

```
 private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logob,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(foradmin.this, notificationTitle,notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }
```

Trying to generate notification on app,but i got error cannot resolve `setLatestEventInfo()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot Resolve Method setLatestEventInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo) ?

Comment: actully i want to create when i select sendtoapp option in my project then one notification is send to all registerd mobile no in my database

Comment: plz somebody help me...

Comment: what is your android-target version ?

Comment: target version is 23 and minsdkversion is 8

Comment: i was check your given link try this but error remains same

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html)
This method was removed in M (api 23). So if your compile SDK version is set to api 23+ you'll see this issue. Either refer the above mentioned question and it's answers or set android-target to less than 23 .

Comment: when i refer above mentioned question then after running app forcefully closed and the error is shown  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.Notification$Builder

Answer (score 0):

try like this. it works perfectly.Hope this helps.Thanks

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
        builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");               
        builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();

        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager.notify(11, myNotication);
```

Comment: when i refer above mentioned codethen after running app forcefully closed and the error is shown java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.Notification$Builder.......

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this); this is the solution of my problem...thanks for your efforts