# Android Send Notice App

Tags: android

I am creating an android application for my college project. I want to include a notice board which will send notification to all the same apps if a notice is posted. And people who are logged in can view the notice. The notice will be stored in MySql database containing a table notice having 5 tables:
    NOTICE-NUMBER NOTICE-DETAIL NOTICE-TIME NOTICE-DATE POSTED-BY. I searched everywhere but all i found is Google Cloud Messing
    API or REST API to do this. But I dont want to use those. I just want to store the notices posted into the database and if someone logs in he/she gets the notification that New Notice Posted and will be able to view it. I havent completed the Java code yet, just need the idea how to do it. Please If Anyone Can Help. THANK YOU!!

```
My XML code: activity_notice.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="RECENT NOTICES"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0612"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/noticeText"
        android:hint="Post Notice"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/sndnoticeBut"
        android:src="@drawable/send1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/noticeText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noticeText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/noticeText" />

</RelativeLayout>


Java code: Notice.java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

public class Notice extends Activity
{
    ImageButton notbut;
    EditText nottxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notice);

        notbut=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sndnoticeBut);
        nottxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.noticeText);

        notbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tittle = "You Have Received A Message";
                String subject = "New Notice Posted";
                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
                String body = nottxt.getText().toString().trim();

                NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.noti, tittle, System.currentTimeMillis());
                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

                notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), subject, body,pending);
                notif.notify(0, notify);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are sending the notification to an external server?

Comment: If you don't want to use GCM, just go for Sockets (not recommended one)!
But I personally prefer GCM (and also nowadays FCM - Firebase Cloud Messaging which is advanced version of GCM). I suggest you to go through the documentation by Google which is very simple (also for beginner)!
Best of Luck!

Comment: I am not sending it to external database. Only local host. Just for project purpose. It does not have a register page. Only login page and ID and Password for all Students And Teachers are pre inserted in database. That is why i do not want to use GCM or FCM. I went through all the tutorials possible but did not find a suitable one, the kind I want.

Comment: Just to get it right, you don't send the notification to an server but want other devices to be able to query for the notification? Or is the App only installed on one device and people may login in the app to receive the notification?

Comment: The app is only installed in AVD. Not a real device. So when i send a notice, it should get stored in database, just simple with date, time, and logged in user name. I logout again, and then when i log in with different user, notification should come New Notice Posted, and the message displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So there is only one device and one app on that device. The app has multiple users that are stored in a sqlite database. Each user may write a notification within the app. When another user logs in, then the written notification should be shown to him/her.

What you need is the ability to differentiate if a certain user has seen a notification or not. I would suggest that you extend the users table to add an last_login column if such column does not exist yet. Then every time a user logs in use that column to fetch notifications that were posted post the date of the last login. This should yield notifications the user has not seen. Display the notifications and set the last_login column of that user to the recent date so that old notifications are not returned the next time the user logs in.

Comment: Ohh.. Ok Thank You Sir. I Will try it.

Comment: How will I declare the push notification? app is not taking setLatestEventInfo

Comment: Please help.. How will I send push notification without using GCM or FCM??!

Comment: Oh and I forgot... In the layout how can I add something like a container which will display all the posts when other users log in? Like in edit text I enter something and click post or send, It will show the text in a text view above. Thank You..!!

Comment: Uhm, please do some research on your own. You'll gain nothing by asking questions until the app is finished. Also nowadays the Internet is full of tutorials for all possible use cases. Nothing like 10 years ago. So for notifications see [this so entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345768/cannot-resolve-method-setlatesteventinfo). For the later question see [any ListView tutotial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).