# java - How to fix The method setLatestEventInfo(AlarmService_Service, String, CharSequences, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification

Tags: javascript, java, c#, android, eclipse

How to fix The method setLatestEventInfo(AlarmService_Service, String, CharSequences, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification

please any help to fix this error

[image: this is the screenshot of the error]

this is the script :

```
/**
 * Show a notification while this service is running.
 */
private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
  CharSequence text = "Doctor Jokes SF";

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text,System.currentTimeMillis());

  Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 // Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
 notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
      notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, quote.getBody(), text, contentIntent);

    notification.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
  //Define sound URI
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notification.sound = soundUri;

    // Send the notification.
    // We use a layout id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
    mNM.cancelAll();
    mNM.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: javascript java or c# ? what is it? 100% not javascript

Comment: this script is taken from a file named AlarmService_Service.java from the code source of a game , so this is javascript !

Comment: no it isnt, javascript is a different language than java.

Comment: yes sir you're right , but if you know how to fix that please tell me how

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's depracated and you should use the Notification Builder. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346246/2301416).