# Cannot resolve setLatestEventInfo method

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I recently developed an app, however, Android studio no longer supports the `setLatestEventInfo` method, therefore, I have tried to change this method to `Notification.Builder` method. However, I am struggling, therefore I would like someone to please support me into changing this method into `Notification.Builder` method.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Fall Detector";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);


        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Fall Detector";
        CharSequence contentText = "Running";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,StartActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);


        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

I have tried the below, however, it says that it cannot resolve symbol contentintent.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Fall Detector";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)

                .setContentTitle("Fall Detector")
                .setContentText("Running")
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.build();
        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: "I am struggling" -- please edit your question and show what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. There are quite literally dozens of existing questions on this topic, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32345768/115145). If you do not want people marking your question as a duplicate, you need to explain, **in detail**, what makes your question different from the existing ones.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I have amended the code, however, still getting same message which says cannot resolve symbol contentintent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the below, however, it says that it cannot resolve symbol contentintent.

That is because you failed to copy some lines from your original code into your revised code:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,StartActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
```

Have those in your revised code before you start configuring the `Notification.Builder`.

Comment: I have tried the below, however, it says that it cannot resolve symbol contentintent.

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: As I wrote, have those in your revised code **before you start configuring the `Notification.Builder`**. You have them **after** you start configuring the `Notification.Builder`. So, for example, you could put them as the first lines in your code snippet.

Comment: I have done that, however, now I am receiving an error message which says  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference

Comment: @ElderlyWatch: You got rid of your `mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);` line. You need to assign a value to `mNotificationManager` before you use it.