# Alternative way on how to change setLatestEventInfo in notification receiver

Tags: java, android-activity, notifications

Hi i got stock in this point wherein "setLatesEventInfo" has an error. i know that setLatestEventInfo doesnt run on API 23 and up. can someone help me on how to make this code run ? i mean alternative way , same function but different coded. this is a receiver function. i am doing a notification on my Mainactivity. The only error here is the receiver ,i tried the builder notification , but since this is a receiver ,builder cant apply

Receiver.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by my pc on 12/1/2015.
 */
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Object ACTION = "MyNotification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do what you want here
            Variables.numMessages++;
            generateNotification(context,"MyNotification");
        }
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_od_icon_24dp;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        // String subTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        String subTitle = "some text";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
        //To play the default sound with your notification:
        //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    int LED_ON_MS = 200;
    int LED_OFF_MS = 600;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onGenNoti(View v) {

        // Check readCount
        Variables.readCount = Variables.numMessages;

        PendingIntent pIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        if (Variables.numMessages > 0) {
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTicker("You Have " + Variables.numMessages + " message")
                    .setContentTitle("test")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_od_icon_24dp)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
            noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            noti.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
            noti.ledOnMS = LED_ON_MS;
            noti.ledOffMS = LED_OFF_MS;
            noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the third time in a day that you post about the same problem. Instead of posting a new question multiple times, edit your existing question into the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem that you're asking about. For example: I doubt the `noti.ledARGB...` lines have anything to do with the problem. Test if your problem still exists without them. If so so, remove the lines from the question and reduce the amount of stuff you ask us to consider. Also: I don't see any use of Firebase in the code or question, so  will remove that tag.

Answer (score 5):

Now you have to generate your notification like this

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    Notification notification  = builder
            .setContentIntent(yourPendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis();)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message).build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(notifId, notification);
```