# error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(Context,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)

Tags: java, android

I am not able to update the app with API 26.
The following error appears in when I try to run the project

Error:

> "ServerRunningNotification.java": error: cannot find symbol method
>   setLatestEventInfo(Context,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)

This is my code snippet which having Error

Code:

```
public class ServerRunningNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = ServerRunningNotification.class.getSimpleName();

    private final int NOTIFICATIONID = 7890;
    public String iptext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive broadcast: " + intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(FtpServerService.ACTION_STARTED)) {
            setupNotification(context);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(FtpServerService.ACTION_STOPPED)) {
            clearNotification(context);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setupNotification(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting up the notification");
        // Get NotificationManager reference
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        // get ip address
        InetAddress address = FtpServerService.getLocalInetAddress();
        if (address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to retreive the local ip address");
            return;
        }
         iptext = "ftp://" + address.getHostAddress() + ":"
                + Settings.getPortNumber() + "/";

        // Instantiate a Notification
        int icon = R.drawable.ftp_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = String.format(
                context.getString(R.string.notif_server_starting), iptext);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        // Define Notification's message and Intent
        CharSequence contentTitle = context.getString(R.string.notif_title);
        CharSequence contentText = String.format(context.getString(R.string.notif_text),
                iptext);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, FTP_Start_Stop.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification
                .setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        // Pass Notification to NotificationManager
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATIONID, notification);

        Log.d(TAG, "Notication setup done");
    }

    private void clearNotification(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clearing the notifications");
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        nm.cancelAll();
        Log.d(TAG, "Cleared notification");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification), `setLatestEventInfo(Context,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)` method was removed in Android M (API 23). So it won't work in API versions above 23.

Comment: How do I replace this line?

Comment: // Define Notification's message and Intent

Comment: @AdBahia see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012544/alternative-way-on-how-to-change-setlatesteventinfo-in-notification-receiver

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand little of java and I could not solve the problem yet. The references are different. I can not replace the line: // Define Notification's message and Intent

Comment: @AdBahia I cannot see the difference. Please clarify.